# Screen recorder with zoom functionality and mouse highlighting

Tags: windows, gratis, screen-recording

During the recording, I need to zoom at the place where the mouse cursor is. So, I need software where I can press and hold a button (or something like that) to zoom in and when I release the button it zooms out.

Also, I need a yellow circle or something similar to be around the mouse cursor to make it clearer.

I need free software and portable is better.

Comment: And you need this functionality live and not in post production, is that correct?

Comment: No, not live. I just need to record my screen and I'll upload the video later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minitool Video Converter is a great software for screen recording on windows. It has Video Converter in its name. But it also has a function to record the screen. It also supports mouse highlighting.

Link to download it -
https://cdn2.minitool.com/?p=vc&e=vc-free

Some screenshots -

[image: Minitool Video Converter Screenshot]

[image: Minitool Screen Recorder Screenshot]

You can find the full tutorial for Minitool Video Converter on this site - https://videoconvert.minitool.com/video-converter/minitool-video-converter-manual.html

It also has many other features like the youtube video download and video converter. It can convert 1080p to 4k, mp4 to mp3, 4k to 780p and much more. It supports a wide range of video and audio formats.